# Not able to integrate with Salesforce CPQ

Tags: docusignapi

I installed docusign and docusign for CPQ on my demo org, but i am not able to see any of the fields or related sections under the Quote Document object. I tried to proceed with the integration and finished the steps required on the docusign website, but when i send out a document i am not able to get a response back.

Answer (score 0):

To add Quote Document Object to DocuSign

Login to DocuSign and go to Admin.
On the Integrations sidebar, select Connect.
On the Salesforce connection sidebar, select Actions, and then select Edit.
On the Salesforce Connect Object page, go to the Connect Objects section. Select New Object, and then select Salesforce Object.
Change the object from inactive to active.
Set the value of the Select Salesforce Object picklist to Quote Document.
Set the Object Name to Quote Document.
Enter a description.

It also sounds like you have a write-back issue here is a troubleshooting article that may be able to help: https://support.docusign.com/articles/Why-aren-t-my-completed-envelopes-being-shown-in-Salesforce